# Let's go vs Let's get going

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I watched an English lesson where it was claimed that there is no difference between the expressions "Let's go" and "Let's get going". Is this really the case?

Comment: Not an expert but I don't think so. *Let's get going* sounds less assertive than *Let's go*

Answer (score 3):

Since "get going" means something like "put in motion", "let's go" and "let's get going" practically mean the same. Both refer to a state where certain individuals do not move but are asked to do so. Anyway, get going, due to its wording, sounds somewhat more active than simply to go. To be asked to get going seems a bit more motivating and urgent than "let's go".